# How to select column a, column b, column c with separated by comma all values, column d with separated by comma all values, column e select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm migrating a database from Oracle to Microsoft SQL Server.

`wm_concat()` is not working in SQL Server, for that I used

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + alca_kiosk_machines.kiosk_machine_name 
FROM alca_kiosk_machines;

PRINT @Names
```

but how to select with two more columns in select ie `(name, id, coalesce(machineNames))`

Comment: What has been tried? and what are those results? and what are the expected results?  How can I duplicate this failure on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 

SELECT @Names = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + kiosk_machine_name
        FROM alca_kiosk_machines
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,1
    ,''
)


PRINT @Names
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2017 or newer, than you can use `STRING_AGG` function:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(kiosk_machine_name)
FROM alca_kiosk_machines
```

Comment: STRING_AGG it shows 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name. we are using Microsoft Sql

Comment: @dharaneeswaran I mentioned that it is for 2017 version or higher.